# ASP.NET MVC - Need help to decide on how to pass two models in a view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, tuples, viewmodel

I have a search screen where there are multiple fields to search on and there is a partial view to display the searched result.
Now, I have created a view-model in which all the search fields are there along with a list of the class itself.

```
    public class ClaimDataViewModel
{
    public string CLAIM_NUM { get; set; }
    public string LINE_SUFFIX { get; set; }
    public string CLAIMANT_NAME { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DUE_DATE { get; set; }
    public string MRP_LINE_STATUS { get; set; }
    public string CLAIM_HANDLER_NAME { get; set; }
    public decimal FULL_VALUE_AMT { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ClaimDataViewModel> ClaimDataViewModelList { get; set; } 
}
```

I am using the model to pass information to controller and then fill the list inside the viewmodel and pass it back to the view. Invoking the partial view and passing the list to it.

Please let me know if this is right or should I use tuple to pass the viewmodel along with the list of viewmodel.

Comment: A `Tuple` will never work if you view is for editing data. What your doing is fine.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Now I have a question that is there any harm in creating a list of the class inside the class itself ??

Comment: No of course not. And its common for hierarchical data (for example to represent folders or menu items where you have properties for a menu, and then `List<Menu> ChildMenus`)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use viewmodel because it's lightweight and fast

```
//Product.cs
public class Product
{
    public Product() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

}

//ProductCategory.cs
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

here is your viewmodel.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Product Category")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
 }
```

**Why We Use ViewModel**

1. If you need to pass more than one thing to a strongly-typed view
   (which is best practice),
       you will generally want to create a separate class to do so.
2. This allows you to validate your ViewModel differently than your
   domain model for
       attribute-based validation scenarios
3. Can be used to help shape and format data.
       e.g: need a date or money value formatted a particular way?
             ViewModel is the best place to do it.
4. The use of a ViewModel can make the interaction between model and view more simple

Comment: i think you have some valid point to justify your answer. but i think it depend on of condition.what to use tuple or viewmodel